# Can Bazel batch N of M files that need rebuilding into a single command?

Tags: bazel

The Google Bazel build tool makes it easy enough to explain that each CoffeeScript file in a particular directory tree needs to be compiled to a corresponding output JavaScript file:

```
# Runs "coffee" 100 times if there are 100 files:
# will run slowly if most of them need rebuilding.

[genrule(
  name = 'compile-' + f,
  srcs = [f],
  outs = [f.replace('src/', 'static/').replace('.coffee', '.js')],
  cmd = 'coffee --compile --map --output $$(dirname $@) $<',
) for f in glob(['src/**/*.coffee'])]
```

But given, say, 100 CoffeeScript files, this will invoke the coffee tool 100 separate times, adding many seconds to the compilation process.

Alternatively, this can be written as a single command that takes 100 files as input and produces 100 files as output:

```
# Runs "coffee" once on all the files:
# very slow in the case that only 1 file was edited.

coffee_files = glob(['src/**/*.coffee'])

genrule(
  name = 'compile-coffee-files',
  srcs = coffee_files,
  outs = [f.replace('src/', 'static/').replace('.coffee', '.js') for f in coffee_files],
  cmd = 'coffee --compile --map --output @D $(SRCS)',
)
```

Is there any way to explain to Bazel that coffee can be invoked with many files at once, and that if N of the targets are out of date, then only the N source files should be supplied to the `coffee` command, instead of the full list of all targets whether they need rebuilding or not?

Answer (score 4):

Are coffeescript files independent of one another? If the first one works, where each file is run through `coffee` separately, then it would seem so. In that case, the first one will actually give you the most parallelism and incrementality.

Even if running coffee 100 times is slower than running coffee once with 100 files, you'll only be paying that cost the first time you compile everything. When you change 1 file, the other 99 won't be recompiled. But, if the startup time of `coffee` is so great that the 100 files is actually negligible, you might as well stick with compiling them all in one big genrule.

One way to compromise between the two extremes is to create a macro: http://bazel.io/docs/skylark/macros.html

```
def compile_coffee(name, srcs):
  native.genrule(
    name = name,
    srcs = srcs,
    outs = [f.replace('src/', 'static/').replace('.coffee', '.js') for f in srcs],
    cmd = 'coffee --compile --map --output @D $(SRCS)',
  )
```

and then you can use the `compile_coffee` macro in your build files, organizing your build into appropriately sized targets:

```
load("//pkg/path/to:coffee.bzl", "compile_coffee")

compile_coffee(
  name = "lib",
  srcs = glob(["*.coffee"]))
```

There's also full skylark rules: http://bazel.io/docs/skylark/rules.html but if coffee script files don't really depend on each other, then this probably isn't necessary.

There's also persistent workers: http://bazel.io/blog/2015/12/10/java-workers.html which allows you to keep a running instance of coffee around so that you don't have to pay the startup cost, but the binary has to be well behaved, and is a bit more of an investment because you typically have to write wrappers in order to wire everything up.

Answer (score 0):

This will pass 20 files at a time to the CoffeeScript compiler:

`BUILD`:

```
load(":myrules.bzl", "coffeescript")

coffee_files = glob(["src/*.coffee"])

# 'coffeescript' is a macro, but it will make a target named 'main'
coffeescript(
    name = "main",
    srcs = coffee_files
)
```

`myrules.bzl`:

```
def _chunks(l, n):
    n = max(1, n)
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

def coffeescript(name, srcs):
    i = 0
    all_outs = []
    for chunk in _chunks(srcs, 20):
        chunk_name = "{}-{}".format(name, i)
        outs = [f.replace('src/', 'static/').replace('.coffee', '.js') for f in chunk] + \
               [f.replace('src/', 'static/').replace('.coffee', '.js.map') for f in chunk]
        all_outs += outs
        native.genrule(
            name = chunk_name,
            srcs = chunk,
            outs = outs,
            cmd = "coffee --compile --map --output $(@D)/static $(SRCS)"
        )
        i += 1

    # make a filegroup with the original name that groups together all
    # of the output files
    native.filegroup(
        name = name,
        srcs = all_outs,
    )
```

Then, `bazel build :main` will build all the CoffeeScript files, 20 at a time.

But this does have some weaknesses:

- If one CoffeeScript file gets modified, then 20 will get recompiled. Not just one.
- If a file gets added or deleted, then lots of files -- basically, from that point until the end of the list of files -- will get recompiled.

I've found that the best approach has been to do what @ahumesky suggested: Break things up into reasonably sized Bazel "packages", and let each package do a single compilation.